# Mutiple Data Source for a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am in a process to support multiple `data source` to show data in a component via props & store.

The idea is to build a list component, which will load the data from the store if no props present. Otherwise, show the data from props. Thus, I am ensuring `reusability` in the context of `search` functionality and normal `listing view`.

Here is the code looks like,

```
<template>
  <div>
    <li v-for="user in this.dataSource" :key="user.age">
      {{ user.name }}
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    userData: {
      type: Array,
      default: null,
    }
  },
  created() {
    // dispatch action to get user data
    this.$store.dispatch("GET_USER_DATA");
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dataSource: this.userData !== null ? this.userData: this.$store.state.users
    };
  }
};
```

As of now, the store holds just static data. But in the context of REST it will be async in nature. So sometimes, I see no data.

So my question is that is this logic of `dataSource` can be improved further?

Thanks
Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `dataSource` to computed property. It will automatically re-computed when `this.userData` is changed or `this.$store.state.users` is changed

```
computed: {
  dataSource() {
    return this.userData !== null ? this.userData: this.$store.state.users
  }
}
```

For more information about computed in Vuejs, please check [the document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad approach anyways.
Store should be used to contain the data and components should just "show" it and manipulate it through actions and mutations.

So in this case, I'd remove the `props`, `created` and `data` part and add a `getter` to the store which should be implemented in a `computed` in the component. Nothing fancy here.

You shouldn't need to manually load the data with a proper store setup. Always make a getter and "load" it into the component with a `computed`.